# How to ask for a particular thing from user who is confusing Bot in api.ai?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, dialogflow-es

I am trying to make a self BOT with the help of API.AI with telegram.
my bot is related to question and answer.
user can ask movie rating and review from the BOT. like

```
user- Review and rating of terminator
BOT - here BOT respond with terminator rating and review.
```

NOW
if user trying to confuse BOT with

```
user- rating and review of Terminator and Titanic
```

Now this will be a confusing situation for BOT so how can BOT ask user for a particular movie or how should respond BOT.

Comment: the bot should respond "don't mess with me, remember about Terminator..."

Comment: @PRMoureu i am not getting you

Comment: @PRMoureu So how can i set like this response

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [Default Fallback Intent](https://api.ai/docs/intents#fallback_intents).

To add a new fallback intent:

- Go to Intents from the left side menu
- Click on the three dot “more options” menu next to ‘Create Intent’
- Choose ‘Create Fallback Intent’

Comment: this is not going to help me. i am trying it but i think this will not work in my case

Comment: i create but when trying to ask terminator and tittanic it showing me terminator rating and review

Comment: @chandra you need to set a unique set of input contexts for each fallback intent